# how do i Select from table with WHERE condition and desc order using query builder function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to select comments in my `Comments` table. And I want to select them based on a Report Number and in descending order using the codeigniter 3 query builder functions.

I got this code here in my model and if I `var_dump` it just doesn't work the way I want to.
this is the code I have so far:

```
$this->db->order_by('Date', 'DESC');
$query=$this->db->where("Comments", array('ReportNum' => $report));
$row=$query->result();
```

This what i get when I `var_dump` it:

```
object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#27 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#16 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(5) ["client_info"]=> string(13) "mysqlnd 8.0.9" ["client_version"]=> int(80009) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.4.20-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(100420) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(571) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } ["result_id"]=> object(mysqli_result)#26 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> int(0) } ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#28 (5)
```

^ this comes before the desired array.

Comment: with *helper function* I suppose you mean query builder? what does var_dump show, why or what *is not working the way you want*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `get` clause to query a table; you can either use:

`where()` and `get()`:

```
$this->db->order_by('Date', 'DESC');
$this->db->where( array('ReportNum' => $report));
$query=$this->db->get("Comments");
$row=$query->result();
```

or `get_where()`:

```
$this->db->order_by('Date', 'DESC');
$query=$this->db->get_where("Comments", array('ReportNum' => $report));
$row=$query->result();
```

[About CI 3.x query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).